# Using Ruby's gsub with a string containing "\0"

Tags: ruby, gsub

I'm having trouble using gsub correctly:

Given this code:

```
"replace me".gsub(/replace me/, "this \\0 is a test")
```

The result is:

```
 "this replace me is a test"
```

But what I am expecting is:

```
"this \0 is a test"
```

How do I use gsub to get the result I want?

Comment: The \0 is a backreference that gets replaced by the entire match, and it's not unique to Ruby. (You usually see them as \1, \2, etc. \0 is more rare)

Comment: When `'\0'` is found in single quotes (as the last parameter to `gsub` usually is), it is equivalent to `"\\0"` in double quotes since you can't have any escape sequence other than `'\\'` or `'\''` in single quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escape it with another backslash so that `gsub` will know you want `"\\0"`.

```
"replace me".gsub(/replace me/, "this \\\\0 is a test")
```

**(Edit)** if by `"\0"` you meant the byte `0x00`, do this:

```
"replace me".gsub(/replace me/, "this \0 is a test")
```

Comment: Nah I didn't mean "\0" as the byte 0x00

Comment: Say I have the string `string = 'this \0 is a test'` and I want to use this string as the second argument to gsub. Would `string.gsub(/\\/,'\\\\')` work? How do I escape `string` so that the `\0` is not replaced with the match?

Comment: If the replacement text isn't a string literal that you can't escape whilst coding then this will escape them:  `string.gsub!(/(\\\d)/,'\\\\\1')` - There are five slashes in the replacement string. Each two become one in the actual string, so `gsub` sees `\\\1` meaning one backslash followed by the first match of the regex `\\\d`. That is itself one backslash followed by a digit. So, say the input string contains `\0` it will be converted to `\\0` or literally two backslashes followed by a digit zero.